# What is the difference between Sequential and Concatenate of keras while creating input for model?

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

What is the difference between Sequential and Concatenate of keras while creating input for model?

I have seen two way of creating layers with Sequential where we just define the shape of the input, but the another way is creating  inputs with Concatenate.

What is the difference between these two approach ?

Below are approaches:

**Approach 1:**

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=(2,), kernel_regularizer='l1', activation=tf.sigmoid))


model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.experimental.RMSprop(learning_rate=my_learning_rate),
                loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
                metrics=METRICS)
```

Approach 2:
Link : [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/eng-edu/blob/main/ml/cc/exercises/binary_classification.ipynb?utm_source=mlcc&utm_campaign=colab-external&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=binary_classification_tf2-colab&hl=en#scrollTo=3tmmZIDw4JEC).

```
  my_inputs = {
    # Features used to train the model on.
    'median_income': tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,)),
    'total_rooms': tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,))
  }
# Use a Concatenate layer to concatenate the input layers into a single tensor.
  # as input for the Dense layer. Ex: [input_1[0][0], input_2[0][0]]
  concatenated_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()(my_inputs.values())
  dense = layers.Dense(units=1, name='dense_layer', activation=tf.sigmoid)
  dense_output = dense(concatenated_inputs)
  """Create and compile a simple classification model."""
  my_outputs = {
    'dense': dense_output,
  }
  model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=my_inputs, outputs=my_outputs)

  # Call the compile method to construct the layers into a model that
  # TensorFlow can execute.  Notice that we're using a different loss
  # function for classification than for regression.
  model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.experimental.RMSprop(learning_rate=my_learning_rate),
                loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
                metrics=METRICS)
```

Comment: Sadly, your questions doesn't make sense. Why are you comparing a dataframe object and keras class layer? Please add more details.

Comment: Hi @Innat, I have updated the sample. I have seen two way of creating layers with Sequential where we just define the shape of the input, but the another way is creating  inputs with Concatenate, did not find the differance in terms of logical operations.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Are you aware of sequential and functional modeling in keras? If not, you may check [this blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/model-sub-classing-and-custom-training-loop-from-scratch-in-tensorflow-2-cc1d4f10fb4e) for references.

Comment: Thanks @Innat,  Functional API gives more flexibility compare to Sequential  API. But still while using Functional API what is the need of Concatenate layer here.

Comment: The need of using, isn't it specific to user? Also, in the above code, two feature vectors (median_income, total_rooms) are mentioned. Now, if you want to build a model which takes such inputs (multi-input) and want to combine them at the beginning, you probably would use concat method. But note, in the data loading time, if we combine  these feature vectores beforehand, then you can build a single-input model and no concat method would require.

Comment: May be I need to improve my core concepts, thanks @Innat

Comment: Lastly, the modelling approaches (using concat or not) solely depends on us, like how we want to build the model. I would suggest to check out keras site, especially developer guide and code example section. It's a great resources.